# Geocoder + Rails 3.2 // SQLException: no such column: distance:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rails-geocoder

I keep getting the same error when I try to apply Geocoder gem to my search form. You will see 2 different queries in Event Controller. If I use them on their own they work great. But, I use them together, as shown here, it does throw the error.

```
QLite3::SQLException: no such column: distance: SELECT "events"."id" AS t0_r0, "events"."header_id" AS t0_r1, "events"."start_date" AS t0_r2, "events"."finish_date" AS t0_r3, "events"."address" AS t0_r4, "events"."place" .......
```

Event model

```
scope :non_timetable, joins(:header).where(headers: {weekly: false})
```

Event Controller

```
def search

@events_casual = Event.non_timetable.near(params[:search_where], 20)
@events_casual  = @events_casual.where("events.finish_date >= ?", @time).where((["CAST(headers.title_es as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_en as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_eu as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_fr as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"])).includes(:header).order("events.start_date ASC")
...

end
```

It seems like i had to specify table name for the Geocoder query. But, I have no idea how. Any help much appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same Issue [Geocoder SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: lon:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122025/geocoder-sqlite3sqlexception-no-such-column-lon). But I recommend you to go through the Geocoder documentation for [Distance Queries in SQLite](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#distance-queries-in-sqlite). And the [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast). Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The rebooting did not work! I am aware of the limitations in SQLite. However, as far as I understand it should work. nope?
There is also some info in here, https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/42 . But to not avail.

Comment: I am not sure but probably its a version of Geocoder problem. Are you trying with latest version ? In the link you have given one suggestion is to use gem from this branch : gem 'geocoder', :git => 'git://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder.git', :branch => 'no_grouping'
 Can you please try that ?

Comment: I tried and got this error. fatal: ambiguous argument 'no_grouping': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions. What does it mean?

Comment: Oh, I think the branch has removed from repository. Ok, get rid of it and try with MySQL, if that works

Comment: I am using SQLite in development and PG in production.  Should not work that way? I am using Heroku

Comment: It should work. Have you added latitude:float longitude:float fields in modal ? Have you gone through RailsCast 273 episod ? He is using the same database and works for him. http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28307/discussion-between-anand-soni-and-sergio-nekora)

Comment: yeap. That tutorial was my starting point. I got those two field in the model. When I use model.nearbys works fine. Even @events_casual = Event.non_timetable.near(params[:search_where], 20)  works fine on its own. It just doesn't work when combined with the other query. At the same time, the other query also works on its own.